# Pandas dataframe- Count rows where specific column is NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, nan

I need to count the number of rows of a dataframe where the column Salary is Nan?

I tried this approach

```
print(df.count(df[df['Salary'].isnull()]))
```

but I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fdpires\Desktop\MEI\DESCO\ex2.py", line 69, in <module>
    print(df.count(df[df['Salary'].isnull()]))
  File "C:\Users\fdpires\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 9846, in count
    axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
  File "C:\Users\fdpires\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 550, in _get_axis_number
    return cls._AXIS_TO_AXIS_NUMBER[axis]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'DataFrame'
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: what error? show us your error messgae ,

Answer (score 2):

```
df[df['Salary'].isnull()].shape[0]
```

Comment: It worked. What does shape[0] do?

Comment: @FábioPires it returns number of rows in your dataframe, `shape[1]` is columns number

Comment: if I wanted to count the number of NaN for each column of my dataframe would I have code it individually for each one or there is a method for that?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
df['Salary'].isnull().sum()
```

if you wanna count the number of Nan in each column , simply :

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

Comment: I tried that but I got an message of a reduction

Comment: @FábioPires provide a sample dataframe then